# Google Cloud Storage - How to access folders and files like static resources inside bucket - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to use Google Cloud Storage for all static resources - images etc

The example is injecting 1 file, but I want to access many files - given a name

```
@Value("gs://${gcs-resource-test-bucket}/hello.txt")
private Resource gcsFile;
```

I am also not interested in iterating - as I have folders inside bucket, and dont want to iterqate all 100 files or so everytime

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName);

for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
  System.out.println(blob.getName());
}
```

Is there a way to access files like gs://somestringfilename ?

Don't know how to use this property to get access to files

```
You can also serve static resources by reading them from a bucket.
 spring.web.resources.static-locations=gs://p*
```

Assume that I have  a rest controller to supply a file name, how can I get file from cloud storage?

Comment: Are your resources public?

Comment: not public. app is reading, so assuming it is service account. Issue is not permissions, but  how to access files by name

Comment: Trying -  Page<Blob> blobs =
             storage().list(
                 bucketName,
                 Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(directoryPrefix));    seems ok, but need to read contents now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using bean

> StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();

a function

private Page folder(String directoryPrefix) {

```
Page<Blob> blobs =
        storage().list(
            bucketName,
            Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(directoryPrefix));

return blobs;
```

}

Usage: directotyPrefix is not just my folder, but also sticking file name

> myfolder/ + filenamewithext

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given statement, You are trying to read or access files from Google Cloud Storage using Java as your language.

For your case, this should work:

```
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
String fileContent = new String(blob.getContent());
System.out.println(fileContent);
```

For further documentation of **Class Blob**, You may refer [here](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html).

You could also have a look into this [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) for more detail.

Comment: I found an answer and will post my answer too. will try this one, as it is different from my solution